# Can i have greek, english and chinese in same mysql database?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have request from a customer to develop a website on english,greek and chinese language. While i know for sure that utf8_general_ci will do for the greek and english, i am not sure if it will work for chinese language.

So question is: can i use utf8_general_ci enconding for the chinese language, or i have to make separate set of tables with different encoding?

Regards, Zoran

Comment: Yes, you can encode Chinese in UTF-8, no probs. Or you can use different encodings for different tables. Or you can use GB18030 for each of the tables (English and Greek are encodable in GB18030). So it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UTF-8` supports practically every language, but more correctly, it supports practically every script.  It will work for English, Greek, and Chinese.  You might need to convert the encoding at some points since some things use different encodings for eastern languages, but the database will be fine as long as everything it gets is in `UTF-8`.